# How to create a SQL ordering based on JOIN values and on today month

Tags: mysql, join

I have two databases

TABLE_ORDERS with `id`,`created`,`user_id`.....`status_id`

TABLE_STATUSES with `it`,`title`,`ordering`,`month`

ordering is an integer for ordering statuses and month is the month number (`01-January`, `02-February`, ...)

I would like to create somethig like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_ORDERS, 
     TABLE_STATUSES 
WHERE 1 
  AND TABLE_STATUSES.month >= '7' 
ORDER BY TABLE_STATUSES.ordering
```

What should be the right syntax?

The wished result is a table of orders ordered by statues like "To be delivered on January, To be delivered on February" that will change automatically month by month.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: *What should be the right syntax?* Shown query code is synthactically correct. But logically - you must add the joining condition(s).

Comment: are there two databases or two tables in a databases?

Comment: what attributes are referenced in the schema

Answer (score 0):

your query can go like this :

```
SELECT TABLE_ORDERS.*, TABLE_STATUSES.month
FROM TABLE_ORDERS INNER JOIN TABLE_STATUSES  
ON TABLE_STATUSES.id = TABLE_ORDERS.status_id
ORDER BY TABLE_STATUSES.ordering
```

An example can be :

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.columnname = table_2.columnname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try
Select * from TABLE_ORDERS o inner join TABLE _STATUSES s ON o.id=s.id WHERE MONTH(s.month)>=7 ORDER BY s.ordering.
You can filter out months gretter than 7.
Good luck.